# how to transmit argv for main in bash

Tags: c, argv, msys2

I am learning the redirect symbol in Unix.I want to use redirect symbol '<' to transmit parameter for main to automatically change argv[1] in main.
Code in main is shown below
`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    switch (atoi(argv[1]))
    {
        case 1:
        .....
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`
If i type **./a.exe 1**,the main function will work in case 1 and argv[1] is 1.However, if i create a script.txt,the content of which is 1 and type **./a.exe < script.txt**,case 1 will not work.And i check the argv[1] is **null**,which is supposed to be 1.
My code is running under Windows10 msys2 and compiler is gcc. Could anyone tell me how can i use '<' or other method.

If my understanding of '<' is wrong or there is something special for use this way to send argv[1] of main

Comment: You can also use `xargs` command. like: `xargs -0 ./a.exe < script.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The redirect operator is different from arguments. Actually, the redirect operator moves the content of the given file into stdin or move the output into a file. Let me explain it more. Consider the following example:

```bash
./a.out > out.txt
```

This redirects your `stdout` (`printf` output written into `stdout` for example) and writes it into `out.txt`.

```bash
./a.out < in.txt
```

This redirects `in.txt` into your `stdin` (`scanf` reads from `stdin` for example).

As you can see, these are different thing and not related to your arguments. If you want, following script reads the `arg.txt` and put its content as arguments for your code.

```bash
./a.out $(cat hello.txt)
```

Comment: Thank you sincerely! And if you mean argv in main can not use '|' or '<' to add?And it seems like argv can only be sent just follow the ./a.out in one command